# Update database with Facebook FB.api callback response?

Tags: facebook

I have a MySQL database that I want to update with a response value that I get when I have uploaded a photo to an album on Facebook with the Facebook .api - JavaScript.

I upload a photo using the code below, and I want to update my database with the `response.id` that is returned after the upload is finished.

How can I update the database, or how can I put the callback value into an classic .asp variable?

```
function uploadphoto(){

    var imgURL = "http://www....myimage.jpg";

    FB.api('/1234xxxxxxxxxxxx/photos/', 'post', {
        message:'somemessage',
        url:imgURL,
    }, function(response){
        if (!response || response.error) {
            alert('Error occured' +response.error);
        } else {
            alert('Post uploaded!\nPost ID number: ' + response.id);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery

```
function uploadphoto(){

var imgURL = "http://www....myimage.jpg";

  FB.api('/1234xxxxxxxxxxxx/photos/', 'post', {
    message:'somemessage',
    url:imgURL,

  }, function(response){

    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Error occured' +response.error);
    } else {
        alert('Post uploaded!\nPost ID number: ' + response.id);
        $.get('ajax/uploadcounter.asp?id=' + response.id);
    }
  }); 
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Frederick, just so I understand it right.
Is that posting it to the uploadcounter.asp page so I can have a request.querystring and get the value there? I guess it does, I have to test it in the morning, thanks!

Comment: Thanks, can I also send my own variable with the post and that I can get that back in the response so I know witch post I should update with the response.id?

Comment: just add the other variables to the the url, thate $.get opens.

Comment: :-) yes of course, I didnt see it!
But how do I send unic value to that variable?
If I want to send a variable - with a unic value - userId like this:
$.get('ajax/uploadcounter.asp?userId=userIdvariable&id=' + response.id);

Im looping out the links that call the function so I have:
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 1</a>
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 2</a>
<a href="#" onClick="uploadphoto(); return false;">Upload photo 3</a>